# Cannot parse UserID from SAML 2.0 response XML

Tags: c#, xml, saml-2.0, onelogin

I'm trying to use a sample application from onelogin.com C# example but it seems to be pretty buggy.  My last remaining problem is trying to parse things like the UserID from the SAML response XML.   I can't seem to find any example C# code for the .NET built in SAML so I'm trying to do it using raw XML tools but I never get a match for the UserID:

```
public string GetNameID()
        {
            XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
            manager.AddNamespace("ds", SignedXml.XmlDsigNamespaceUrl);
            manager.AddNamespace("saml", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion");
            manager.AddNamespace("samlp", "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol");

            XmlNode node = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("saml:Assertion/saml:Subject/saml:NameID", manager);
            // node is now null!
            return node.InnerText; // throws exception
        }
```

Here is my (heavily cut) XML which has had all irrelevant nodes/sections removed:

```
<trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
  <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
    <trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
      <saml:Assertion xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" Version="2.0" ID="pfxefe742da-7d6f-1f2a-85c6-0ab28c701748" IssueInstant="2016-06-14T12:14:56Z" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <saml:Subject>
          <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">example@email.com</saml:NameID>          
        </saml:Subject>
      </saml:Assertion>
    </trust:RequestedSecurityToken>
    </trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponse>
</trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection>
```

Comment: That's not a SAML2 protocol Response. It's a WS-Trust response containing a SAML2 assertion.

Comment: @AndersAbel Thanks - I'm new to this and wasn't sure why I was seeing a different type of response to what I was seeing in online examples. As you know, I've now switched to using your library and test server so this is a non-issue now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use LINQ to XML instead to search for the tag you want:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);
List<XElement> userIDs = (from element in xmlDoc.Descendants()
                          .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName.Contains("NameID"))
                          select element).ToList();
```

You can then access the userIDs with something like:

```
userIDs[index].Value;
```

Or if you want to iterate through the list:

```
foreach (XElement element in userIDs)
{
    element.Value; //Do something with this
}
```

Don't forget to add `using System.Xml.Linq;` to the top of your file!